# Can the ImportExcel Powershell module be used to export data in XLS format (as opposed to XLSX)?

Tags: excel, powershell

The ImportExcel PS module is incredibly helpful, but cannot see a way to export as XLS, which the user requires over XLSX.

Is there a possible with this module? We do not have Excel installed on our servers, hence trying to use this method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this module does not support .xls format.

https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel/issues/323

They do, however, offer a converter cmdlet:
`ConvertTo-ExcelXlsx`
[Repository here](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel/blob/master/Public/ConvertTo-ExcelXlsx.ps1)